# getting variables queried from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, maps

Trying a new method of plotting a marker on google map with my lat/long queried from a data base. when i create variables within the jquery script tag, it works but im not able to make a call outside out that script. But when i try to set those variables with a json_encode from the php array outside of that script, the console returns with

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index:html:29

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          #map {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 900px;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
          function initialize() { 

           var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.4403, -122.5463);
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 10,
              center: myLatlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title:"Hello World!"
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
          }

            var latitude = <?php echo json_encode($lat);?>;
            var longitude = <?php echo json_encode($long);?>;
            var LatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLong;
                title:"Test"
            });
            marker1.setMap(map);
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload = "initialize()">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

PHP to query over database:

```
<?php

require("server_info.php");


$connection=db2_connect($database, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . db2_conn_error());}
$query = "SELECT lat,long FROM SCHOOL";
$stmt = db2_prepare($connection, $query);
$result = db2_execute($stmt);


$lat = array();
$long = array();
while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {
  $lat = $row[0];
  $long = $row[1];
}
//echo json_encode($lat);
//echo json_encode($long);

db2_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: That looks like a JS error, meaning you're probably running this from a .html file, which is generally NOT executed as php. if you do a `view source` on that page, do you see the raw php code?

Comment: @neilsimp1: no. json_Encode takes care of everything. the only thing OP needs to supply is the `;`, really.

Comment: This error often happens when you have HTML in a `.js` file. `.js` files should not have `<script>` around the code.

Comment: if you see the php code AT ALL in your browser, then it's not being executed on the server. e.g. you need to rename it to .php, or tell your server to treat .html files as php scripts.

Comment: @Barmar: if it was a .js file, then the error would be on line 1, since html isn't valid JS at all.

Comment: @MarcB I do notice that the php files seem to be commented out.

Comment: If you want your file to be executed by PHP, it should be named `index.php`, not `index.html`. Or you need to modify the webserver configuration so it sends `.html` files to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your file is named `index.html`. By default, only files with `.php` suffix are executed using PHP. Since it has a `.html` extension, the webserver is just returning the file verbatim to the browser, instead of running it through PHP, so `<?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>` is sent to the client, and that's not valid Javascript.

You should rename it to `index.php`, then it will be executed using PHP, and the variables will be substituted.

But it looks like there's more to the problem than this. You never set the variables `$lat` and `$long` anywhere in the script. You're setting them in a completely different script.

What you probably should be doing is using AJAX to call the query script from Javascript.

Comment: Okay, that sounds about right after doing some research. I'm really unfamiliar with server side web programming, but i will look into ajax.